# how to use a UITableView without a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to use a UITableView as a single selection in my own ViewController, now I can display it but fail to fill the cell or get wrong on how to fill the cell's textlabel. Any suggestion?  ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Implement the protocols for `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate` in `.h` or `.m` then connect the tableview with the first responder `-datasource` and `-delegate` in interface builder and support the protocol required classes in your `.m`.

For datasource it is: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numbersOfRowsInSection`.

Set your `cell.textlabel.text` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: wow,great~UITableViewDataSource works! I think UITableView has two ways for working.One is the common one that is controlled by a UITableViewController, and the other is by UITableViewDataSource.Great! It's wonderful to find this......

Answer (score 0):

You have to register an object as its datasource if you want to fill it.
If you also want to receive events, you also have to implement a delegate

Comment: I use an NSArray as its data source, but fail to display the data.

Comment: your controller must implements UITableViewDataSource protocol, and implements at least -tableView: numberOfRowsInSection: and -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score -1):

You can embed a TableViewController in your ViewController (property) and add the TableViewControllers view to your ViewControllers view (addSubView). Creating cells goes into the TableViewController and works the same way as in the usual case.

Comment: I'm extremely curious of "embed a TableViewController in your ViewController (property) and add the TableViewControllers view to your ViewControllers view (addSubView)". Could you tell more? in detail, plz.